# Unit for the bounds of the IK call in trac_ik_python

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, trac-ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the `get_ik` function provided by [trac_ik_python](http://wiki.ros.org/trac_ik) in the following way-

```
sol = ik_solver.get_ik(qinit,
                       x, y, z,
                       rx, ry, rz, rw,
                       bx, by, bz,
                       brx, bry, brz)
```

Regarding the above IK call, I have following two questions-

1. What is the meaning of bound here? Is it allowed error/ tolerance?
2. What is the unit for the bounds? I assume that for the position it is in meter, and for orientation, it is in degree.

PS: I am operating Baxter robot in ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit PC.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293356/unit-for-the-bounds-of-the-ik-call-in-trac_ik_python/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2018-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-06**:\

> I assume that for the position it is in meter, and for orientation, it is in degree.

Why? 'degree' is not an SI unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm the author of  [trac_ik_python](http://wiki.ros.org/trac_ik). In the Python wrapper we are just exposing the C++ interface. As far as I know, there is no documentation on what exactly the boundaries are, but, commonsense (and a bit of testing when I made the wrapper) makes me think it's the error/tolerance as you name them. Also the units should be the  inherent units of the position/orientation.

So, in short, *bx, by, bz* should be in **meters** and *brx, bry, brz* should be **radians** (as it's the standard unit), and yes, the boundaries are the allowed errors.

Also *brx* should be boundary on rotation on X, so **roll**. In the same case *bry*, **pitch** and *brz* **yaw**.

.

---

Originally posted by [awesomebytes](https://answers.ros.org/users/4672/awesomebytes/) with karma: 66 on 2018-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-06-07**:
Thank you very much! I got it.